# CSV formatting in Jasper Reports

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, ireport

I am exporting a report I created to a CSV file. The export goes fine but the formatting is off and the variable that I have displaying in a text field doesn't show up at all.

The formatting isn't aligning columns properly and it's re-sizing them so that the values don't show up unless you expand the column. Also, the text field displaying my variable $V{reportTotal} is set as a BigDecimal and formatted for currency. This text field doesn't show anything.

Everything looks great when I choose PDF output. What can I do to fix these formatting problems for CSV output?

Comment: I've just checked export data including the `BigDecimal` field to `csv` with help of iReport (4.1.2) - everything is ok

Comment: Did you try export with help of iReport?

Comment: Which program did you use to check output csv file?

Comment: @AlexK I am using iReport 4.0.0 and am checking the csv file with Excel 2010.

Comment: "The formatting isn't aligning columns properly and it's re-sizing them" That's not really a meaningful statement about a CSV file. CSV files do not have columns; they just have lines of text with commas between values. Almost certainly the problem is that you have extra lines in the CSV file which you don't want, and Excel renders this in a way you don't want. Please check your file in a text editor and update the question to make the actual problem clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this sample:

```
<jasperReport ...>
        ...
    <field name="ORDERS_ORDERID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ORDERS_CUSTOMERID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ORDERS_FREIGHT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        ...
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERS_FREIGHT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERS_ORDERID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERS_CUSTOMERID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result is:

> 32.38,10248,VINET
>   11.61,10249,TOMSP
>   65.83,10250,HANAR
>   41.34,10251,VICTE
>   51.3,10252,SUPRD
>   55.09,10260,OTTIK
>   3.05,10261,QUEDE
>   48.29,10262,RATTC

I think you should check your result `csv` file in basic text viewer/editor (for example, Notepad++ or Notepad on Windows).

Comment: My report xml looks pretty much identical to this.

Comment: @Graham As I mentioned before, this is not JasperReports issue. I think that your csv file is ok. You should check it with help of Notepad++, for example