# Formatting jasper report column

Tags: excel, spring-mvc, csv, jasper-reports

I am developing web app using `spring MVC` frame work, in my application i have used `jasper report` for downloading some of the results into `csv` . But i have problem while downloading a report which contains number fields like `credit card number`. Even though credit card number field is of type string in my application, it automatically coverts into integer field when downloaded as `csv` and since the card number is of `length 16-digits` it will be always converted to `exponential form`. How can i solve this problem?. I tried various method but its of no use

Comment: The csv file does not store format for its data. It is just a plain text

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157796/csv-formatting-in-jasper-reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because no matter what you do Excel interrupts series of digits as numbers itself unless you manually specify the format in Excel.There are various solutions in google like adding `'`(single quote) before series of digits stops Excel from interrupting it as integer.But better solution that may work for you is, in your application before saving cerdit card number to database you can divide that string into format something like this `5455-4121-4124-9221`. below is the code that may help you,

```
String cerditcardNum="";
String[] cerditcardnum = new String[10];
cerditcardnum[0]=cerditcardnumber.substring(0,4);
cerditcardnum[1]=cerditcardnumber.substring(4,8);
cerditcardnum[2]=cerditcardnumber.substring(8,12);
cerditcardnum[3]=cerditcardnumber.substring(12,cerditcardnumber.length());
cerditcardNum=cerditcardnum[0]+"-"+cerditcardnum[1]+"-"+cerditcardnum[2]+"-"+cerditcardnum[3];
```